# Update list items based on CSV File.

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with ID, Region and Phone number. I need to run a powershell to update all the items that has ID match to update Region and Phone Number. I have following and not sure if this is going to do it. I am starting with write-host and it shows blank. Any idea

```
$SiteUrl = "http://inside.power.gov"
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$ListName = "Survey List"
$List = $web.Lists[$ListName]

$csv = import-csv "c:\updateddata.csv"

foreach($item in $csv)
{
    $spItems = $List.GetItemById($item.ID)
    write-host $item.Region
    write-host $item.Phone Number
    write-host $spItems.Region Name

    #$spItems["Region Name"] = $item.Region
    #$spItems["Phone Number"] = $item.Phone Number
    #$spItems.SystemUpdate()
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: I updated the code and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was discovered by user:

```
$SiteUrl = "http://inside.power.gov"
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$ListName = "Survey List"
$List = $web.Lists[$ListName]

$csv = import-csv "c:\updateddata.csv"

foreach($item in $csv)
{
    $spItems = $List.GetItemById($item.ID)
    write-host $item.Region
    write-host $item."Phone Number"
    write-host $spItems["Region Name"]

    #$spItems["Region Name"] = $item.Region
    #$spItems["Phone Number"] = $item.Phone Number
    #$spItems.SystemUpdate()
}

$web.Dispose()
```